# Android how to get `pageid` and `title` `ns` keys from valid JSON data?

Tags: android, json

Here my valid JSON Data

```
   {
    "query": {
       "pages": {
          "8691": {
             "pageid": 8691,
             "ns": 0,
             "title": "d"
           }
       }
    }
}
```

this my data how to get `pageid` and `title` values.

`EDIT:` So I get a JSONObject `pages` and I want to get JSONObjects from `pages`, but the problem is that their name is different everytime.So I can't just do json.getJSONObject("8691");. So any suggestions how can I do that?

Comment: You can use Gson lib for parsing json directly into Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try somehing like this :

```
        JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject("{\"query\": {\"pages\": {\"8691\": {\"pageid\": 8691,\"ns\": 0,\"title\": \"d\"}}}}");
        JSONObject jsonOnb = mainJson.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("pages") ;
        JSONObject pagesObj = jsonOnb.getJSONObject(jsonOnb.names().getString(0));
        System.out.println("pageid : " + pagesObj.get("pageid"));
        System.out.println("title : " + pagesObj.get("title"));
```

since your pageId is dynamic, you can get the name of the first index object in your JSONObject

Answer (score 3):

you can parse current json String as for getting `pageid` and `title` :

```
 JSONObject json =new JSONObject("json string");

//get query json object
JSONObject jsonquery =json.getJSONObject("query");

//get pages json object
JSONObject jsonpages =jsonquery.getJSONObject("pages");

//get names for jsonpages
JSONArray namejsonarray = jsonpages.names();

// now get json object from jsonpages
JSONObject jsonnew =jsonpages.getJSONObject(namejsonarray.get(0));

//get pageid from jsonnew json object
String str_pageid =jsonnew.getString("pageid");

//get title from jsonnew json object
String str_title =jsonnew.getString("title");
```

Comment: see edited answer `8691` name is different everytime.So I can't just do json.getJSONObject("8691");

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy.P : now see my answer

Comment: got error from `JSONObject jsonnew =jsonpages.getJSONObject(namejsonarray.get(0));` line `getJSONObject`

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy.P : just use `getJSONObject(namejsonarray.get(0).toString());` or `getJSONObject(namejsonarray.getString(0));` because getJSONObject accept String

Answer (score 2):

```
jsonString="  {
    "query": {
       "pages": {
          "8691": {
             "pageid": 8691,
             "ns": 0,
             "title": "d"
           }
       }
    }
}";

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONObject json_query = json.getJSONObject("query");
JSONObject json_pages = json_query.getJSONObject("pages");
JSONArray pagesjsonarray = json_pages.names();
JSONObject jsonobject =json_pages.getJSONObject(pagesjsonarray.get(0));

 jsonobject .get("pageid");// it will return 8691
 jsonobject .get("title");// it will return d
```

Check this link [see this](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have already got `JSONObject` called `pages`:

```
final JSONObject pages = ...;
final JSONArray names = pages.names();

if (names != null && names.length() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length(); i++) {
        final String name = names.getString(i);
        final JSONObject page = pages.optJSONObject(name);

        if (page != null) {
            final String id = page.getString("pageid");
            final String ns = page.getString("ns");
            final String title = page.getString("title");

            System.out.println("Id " + id);
            System.out.println("ns " + ns);
            System.out.println("title " + title);
        }
    }
}
```